# How to get data from database by using an array of ids in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have an id array in my controller that has checkbox input in a form in views. `$toppings = $this->input->get('topping');`

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 3
  [2] => 4
)
```

I'm trying to get the information relevant to each id in the array from the database.

```
    $toppings = $this->input->get('topping');
    foreach ($toppings as $topping ) {
        $id = $topping;
        $toppinglist = $this->toppingmodel->find_topping($id);
        echo'<pre>'; print_r($toppinglist); die();

    }
```

Model Class -

```
function find_topping($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('Topping', array('id' => $id));
    return $query->row_array(); }

}
```

The output array i'm getting is only the data for the first id

```
Array
(
  [id] => 1
  [slug] => mushroom
  [toppingName] => Mushrooms
  [price] => 50.00
)
```

How can i get all the data relevant to each id in an array. (nested array)
Thank you.

Comment: `$this->db->where_in('Topping', $toppings);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller:-**

```
$toppings = $this->input->post('topping');    //Array         
$toppinglist = $this->toppingmodel->find_topping($toppings);
```

**model:-**

```
function find_topping($idArr = array()){         //Array  
 $query = $this->db->where_in("Topping", $idArr)->get("tablename");
     return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Note:-**
`$idArr = array()` means

make the function have a default value of array otherwise if something else is passed you'll get an error in your query.

Comment: Still an error is thrown. `Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::result_array()`.

Comment: `ids` are in comma seperated values in one column??

Comment: ids are in an array. The array structure is shown at the top of the question

Comment: now try  with my updated answer & let me know what happens??.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm getting the data array now

Comment: @Dilki Sasikala happy to hear , you got it, Enjoy & Happy Coding....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224017/discussion-between-kumar-and-dilki-sasikala).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your SQL query with **WHERE  IN()**.

In Codeignitor you can use **$this->db->where_in($tableName, $arrayOfVales)**. Learn more [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Code Example

```
function find_topping(array $ids)
{
    $query = $this->db->where_in('Topping', $ids);
    return $query->result_array(); 
}
```

Comment: How should i pass the id from the controller. I tried using `db->where_in` but now a type error is thrown saying `Message: Argument 1 passed to toppingmodel::find_topping() must be of the type array, string given,`

Comment: @Dilki Sasikala what you get in `id` or 'array`    `$toppings = $this->input->get('topping');`

Comment: You need to send an array of Ids to function find_topping();